# Azure SQL Server Alternative to FOR..EACH loop

Tags: sql, t-sql, for-loop

I have an Azure SQL database with a table of users 'tbl_User' and a table of Cases 'tbl_Case' which has an 'AllocatedUserName' column. This column is either null (unallocated) or contains the Username of a user in tbl_User.

I would like to be able to loop through tbl_User and for each record, update the first three **unallocated** records in tbl_Case with that User name.

Normally doing this in VBA I would use a For..Each loop and an Update Statement. However, from what I read that is almost certainly the wrong way to do it in T-SQL?

So for example my tbl_User would have:

| UserID | Username | UserRole |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Reviewer |
| 2 | Paul | Reviewer |
| 3 | Mark | Reviewer |

If my tbl_Case looked like this before the procedure:

| CaseID | AllocatedUsername | AllocatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | 01 Sep 2021 |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |
| 8 |  |  |
| 9 |  |  |
| 10 |  |  |
| 11 |  |  |

afterwards it would look like this:

| CaseID | AllocatedUsername | AllocatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | 01 Sep 2021 |
| 2 | John | 08 Sep 2021 |
| 3 | John | 08 Sep 2021 |
| 4 | John | 08 Sep 2021 |
| 5 | Paul | 08 Sep 2021 |
| 6 | Paul | 08 Sep 2021 |
| 7 | Paul | 08 Sep 2021 |
| 8 | Mark | 08 Sep 2021 |
| 9 | Mark | 08 Sep 2021 |
| 10 | Mark | 08 Sep 2021 |
| 11 |  |  |

Any pointers very much appreciated!
Jim

Comment: Please post the table definitions and sample data.  It's likely you don't want to use a loop here (which would be a CURSOR or a WHILE loop in SQL).

Comment: SQL is a set based languages. There's no reason to use FOR loops in any SQL dialect, any database product. You can write an `UPDATE ... FROM .. WHERE` statement that selects the rows you want and modifies them. You can use `FROM (SELECT TOP 10 ...)` in many cases

Comment: I think there's some phrasing problems in your question. You mentioned a concept of "the first three" unallocated records. This implies some kind of ordering (which three are the first three?). So, what are you ordering by? Here's what I think you want to do: "For all of the currently unallocated cases, allocate up to three of them to each user". This then begs a further question: Do you want to allocate them evenly? For example, suppose there are exactly 3 unallocated cases. Do three users each get one case, or does one user get all three cases? If you have 100 users, which users get cases?

Comment: @allmhuran The idea is that it would simply allocate the first 3 unallocated cases (Ordered by CaseID) to User1, the next 3 to User2 and so on. It doesn't matter if it runs out of unallocated cases before it gets to the end of the list of users.
It also doesn't matter how many cases were allocated to a user before the procedure. So if User1 had 8 cases before and User 2 had 0 cases, they would have 11 and 3 afterwards.

Comment: @squillman I have posted some before and after tables - I hope that helps to explain it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which numbers the users and the cases and then matches them together mathematically. For very large amounts of data the performance would likely be bad, in which case you would want to materialise the CTE's as temp tables, with the mathematical expressions (the `row_number` and `* 3` bits) evaluated as columns in the `numberedUsers` and `numberedCases` tables, and indexed, instead of joining on the expression in the final query.

```sql
create table users(userid int primary key);
create table cases(caseid int primary key, userid int, allocatedDate date);

-- sample data. 
-- This solution does not assume that userids or caseids must be monotonically increasing. 
-- Gaps in id's are ok (likely to be the case if id's are generated by identity columns)

insert users
values (23), (24), (30), (40), (41);

insert cases
values (1, null), (2, 24), (5, null), (8, 40), (9, null), (10, null);

with numberedUsers (rn, userid) as 
(
select   row_number() over (order by userid), 
         userid
from     users
),
numberedCases (rn, caseid, userid) as
(
   select row_number() over (order by caseid),
          caseid,
          userid,
          allocatedDate
   from   cases
   where  userid is null
)
update   c
set      c.userId = u.userId,
         c.allocatedDate = getdate()
from     numberedCases c
join     numberedUsers u on c.rn > (u.rn - 1) * 3 and c.rn <= u.rn * 3;
```